# WPF Styles: Styled BasedOn use global Colour

Tags: wpf

I have got a style which changes the look of a button, this button can be different colours however, I do this by using the basedOn property and referencing the main button style but change the background colours. See below:

```
<!--- Small Button Colours -->
<Style BasedOn="{StaticResource ButtonIcoSmall}" TargetType="Button" x:Key="BtnSmGreen">
    <Style.Resources>
        <SolidColorBrush Color="#FF5E8108" x:Key="colour1" />
        <SolidColorBrush Color="#FF5E8107" x:Key="colour2" />
        <SolidColorBrush Color="#FFA1D423" x:Key="colour3" />
    </Style.Resources>
</Style>
```

However, I have no moved these colours our of the style and into a global `SolidBrushColour` tag so I can use these colours in any style without typing the colour in again, and to make it easier to change globally.

```
<!-- Global Colour Scheme -->

<!-- Green -->
<SolidColorBrush Color="#FF8AB71C" x:Key="NorGreen" />
<SolidColorBrush Color="#FF5E8107" x:Key="DarGreen" />
<SolidColorBrush Color="#FFA1D423" x:Key="LigGreen" />

<!-- Grey -->
<SolidColorBrush Color="#FF434953" x:Key="NorGrey" />
<SolidColorBrush Color="#FF22252b" x:Key="DarGrey" />
<SolidColorBrush Color="#FF58616E" x:Key="LigGrey" />

<!-- Blue -->
<SolidColorBrush Color="#FF29A1D5" x:Key="NorBlue" />
<SolidColorBrush Color="#FF1F7297" x:Key="DarBlue" />
<SolidColorBrush Color="#FF36BBF5" x:Key="LigBlue" />

<!-- Red -->
<SolidColorBrush Color="#FFEE4E10" x:Key="NorRed" />
<SolidColorBrush Color="#FFAA3C12" x:Key="DarRed" />
<SolidColorBrush Color="#FFFF6F37" x:Key="LigRed" />
<!-- Global Colour Scheme END -->
```

Now, how can I reference the global colour in my BasedOn style, I have tried `Colour="{StaticResource NorGreen}` this doesn't work, i'm assuming due to the type of data. Below is the style which uses these colours incase you want to take a look at that:

```
<Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                    <WrapPanel>
                        <Border Grid.Column="0"
                                    CornerRadius="5 0 0 5" 
                                    BorderThickness="0"
                                    Background="{DynamicResource colour1}"
                                    Name="buttonIcon">
                            <WrapPanel>
                                <ContentPresenter Grid.Column="0" 
                                                      HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                                                      VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                                                      Margin="{TemplateBinding Margin}" />
                            </WrapPanel>
                        </Border>
                        <Border Grid.Column="0"
                                    CornerRadius="0 5 5 0" 
                                    BorderThickness="0"
                                    Background="{DynamicResource colour2}"
                                    Name="buttonText" >
                            <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Tag}" 
                                                       FontSize="13"
                                                       Foreground="White"
                                                       Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" />
                        </Border>
                    </WrapPanel>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource colour1}" TargetName="buttonText" />
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource colour3}" TargetName="buttonText" />
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource colour3}" TargetName="buttonIcon" />
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to find the answer, actually rather simple :/

`Color="{Binding Source={StaticResource NorGreen}, Path=Color}"`